# Import marathi data from excelsheet to mysql in php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to import data from excel and insert to mysql and excel sheet contain *marathi* data. But it does not give me success. I tried:

```
SET NAMES UTF8;
mysql_query("SET character_set_results = 'utf8', character_set_client = 'utf8', character_set_connection = 'utf8', character_set_database = 'utf8', character_set_server = 'utf8'", $conn);
```

Also set the database `charset=UTF8`.

But still i got `??????` in my database.

How i can store marathi data from excelsheet (.csv file) to mysql in php?

Comment: What does this have to do with phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here:

[Working with Foreign Languages using MySQL and PHP.](http://www.9lessons.info/2011/08/foreign-languages-using-mysql-and-php.html)

Basically, you have to change the collation of your column, where you want to store marathi word. Go to table structure and change collation latin1_swedish_ci to utf8_general_ci.

See, if that helps.